# MVC3 OutputCache VaryByHeader=Cookie not being set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following action method:

```
[HttpGet, Authorize, OutputCache(Duration = 60, VaryByHeader = "Cookie", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any)]
public ActionResult Index()
```

But when I make a request, these are the headers issued:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Fri, 22 Jun 2012 09:56:32 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 22 Jun 2012 09:55:32 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Why isn't it including the Cookie header in the Vary?

I've tried many variations of the `OutputCache` settings but to no avail :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate IIS almost as much as I hate ASP.NET.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2009/10/01/iis-compression-overwrites-the-vary-header-average-rating-0-ratings.aspx

Answer (score 0):

So the response is included in the linked by Andrew Bullock url "page file name", aka "iis compression overwrites the vary header".

But since December 2013 a hotfix is available (found on Andrew Bullock link). As usual, this hotfix may be included in regular patches, so make sure you still need it before applying it.

And as it is "best practice" to explicitly supply information from links rather than only supplying the link (in case the page goes down), here is an abstract :

IIS dynamic compression overwrites the `Vary` header. This seems to apply to IIS from version 5 to version 8 included (when cumulating information from msdn blog and from msdn kb). Either disable IIS dynamic compression, or try applying the hotfix available at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877816/en-us if needed. (This issue may be fixed by regular patches on windows 8.1/2012 R2 series. The hotfix is available starting from IIS 7, personally tested on win7 sp1, not yet on my servers.)

In my specific case, I had also another issue : asp.net was not emitting any `Vary` header (compression enabled or not) with `outputCache` `location` set to `Client`. Setting it to `Downstream` "solved" this additional issue. But of course, this has the side-effect of changing `Cache-Control` from `private` to  `public`. (Now cacheable on proxy instead of just on client browser.)