# ASP.NET MVC Response.Cache VaryByHeaders

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a controller that delivers some response and I am trying to set Cache as shown below,

```
if(string.Equals( Request.Query["cached"] , "true", CultureInfo.IgnoreCase)){
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
   Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
   Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Cookie"] = true;
}
```

When I see the response in Chrome, I see the header,

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Vary header is probably a default, and it is changing.

I do not want to use OutputCache because cache is enabled only for querystring parameter cached=true. When I was using ASP.NET MVC 4, I used to see response

```
Vary:*
```

And now I have upgraded my project to ASP.NET MVC 5, but its no longer working. I only want response to be cached at browser (client) based on login and cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <urlCompression 
          doStaticCompression="true" 
          doDynamicCompression="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Dynamic compression strips off all Vary headers, turning it off makes Vary appear correctly. But now I am dealing with how to enable Gzip for most of our requests, as there is no way to enable dynamic compression without compromising Vary header.

Comment: This workaround works indeed but you loose dynamic compression.

Comment: If you would would still like to have dynamic compression like behavior then you could setup a non Microsoft reverse proxy that both does dynamic compression. It probably does caching better too and helps in ssl offloading.

Answer (score 1):

Since december 2013 you may be able to activate IIS dynamic compression without compromising vary header. Depending on your OS version, you may need to apply a hotfix.

See following kb for the hotfix. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877816

This information was founded on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11156510/1178314

Comment: Does the hotfix also work when run via IIS Express as the problem occurs during development too.

Comment: No, this hotfix seems to apply only to IIS. IIS Express (8.0, VS 2013) on an hotfixed Win7 still loses original Vary values when it performs dynamic compression. (Tested just now, as my usual setup is to use IIS, not IISExpress.)